# Bridge wlan0 to eth0 without DHCP

Tags: settings, wifi, networking

I'm currently trying to set up an access point in my lounge, using my Sony Vaio with elementary OS installed. I have successfully created an access point & can connect to the Internet that way using the network GUI, but it doesn't work when a password is set (another issue) and creates a new network (i.e. runs it's own DHCP server).

What I want to achieve is:

- elementary OS receives internet connection over eth0
- Creates wifi access point using wifi card (wlan0) without creating a new network (i.e. no DHCP)
- Passes traffic from wlan0 to eth0, so that all devices connected to the access point on wlan0 get their IP address from the router (connected via eth0).

Any idea how this can be done? I've been playing around with brctl with limited success at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a solution for your problem, but I am shure you can do this. If you try to setup an acsses point, you can do that for really cheap with a raspberry pi, about 12$ with the new raspberry pi zero. There is a lot of tutorials about this on internet and your computer don't neet to be there or turned on. For this kind of problem feel free to use ubuntu's or debian's documentation and forums.

Answer (score 1):

I would go through [these instructions](http://joost.fock.be/?p=5), but skip the part about the dhcp server and giving the wireless interface and address.

As I don't have a wired connection available for the moment I can't test if it is that simple to adapt to your needs.

Disclaimer: I wrote the instructions.